# Is there a method of passing a type an argument in C?

Tags: c, struct, macros

The other day, I saw a macro I liked in C.

Given a struct embedded into another arbitrary struct, you can retrieve a byte pointer referencing the owner of the embedded struct.

```
#define list_entry(LIST_NODE, STRUCT, MEMBER)       \
    ((STRUCT *) ((uint8_t *) &(LIST_NODE)->next     \
                 - offsetof (STRUCT, MEMBER.next)))
```

This got me thinking, how can I do the same thing using a function? I figured I can pass the `sizeof(struct)` and `sizeof(struct->member)` to perform the arithmetic part but I'm not sure how I can capture the `(STRUCT *)` part.

Comment: You'd also have to pass `offsetof(STRUCT, MEMBER.next)`. Types cannot be passed as parameters in C.

Comment: *"how can I do the same thing using a function?"* - you can't, and there's no reason to to be honest. You would have to pass the address of `member`, `sizeof(struct->member)` and `offsetoff(struct, member)` which is... not practical at all.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I don't think you need to pass `sizeof(struct->member)`

Comment: The problem is that `STRUCT` and `MEMBER` are not values. `MEMBER` is not even a type. It is a lexical token that means anything only after `.` or `->` operators. You could still use some function but it would still have to be wrapped with a macro

Answer (score 0):

You would need one such function for each STRUCT datatype. Such a generic function is not possible in C, hence a macro which is instantiated differently for each type. However, you might consider C++ and templates.

Comment: it is a comment not answer

Comment: I don't think that C++ templates could handle `MEMBER` without preprocessor. AFAIK, C++ has no support for "reflections" yet.